# Is it possible to create a controller for a Magento CMS page?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to create a controller for a Magento CMS Page?

Or do I need to take the page out of the CMS and keep the copy unmanaged?

Comment: I do not have a glue what you are trying to do... Maybe you can explan this in more detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the CMS pages have a controller:  app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php